# Python spyder is not starting on ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, anaconda, spyder

when I try to open it from `anconda-navigator` it give error like:

```
/home/deepankar/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/spyder.sh: line 3:  2111 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) spyder > /home/deepankar/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/spyder-out-1.txt 2> /home/deepankar/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/spyder-err-1.txt
```

And if I try to open it with code spyder it gets error.

```
deepankar@deepankar-VirtualBox:~$ spyder
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Can you please specify the version of anaconda that you've installed?

Comment: my  anaconda version is anaconda 2.7

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by `pyopengl` not being installed. Try installing it by using:

```
conda install pyopengl
```

Comment: @DeepankarSingh Welcome To AskUbuntu, if the answer helped you mark the question as solved by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer. :)

Comment: That didn't work for me.  Interestingly, Spyder was working, until I installed matplotlib. After that, I now get a segmentation error message whenever I try to start Spyder.